# Index for searching in column where the column starts with the provided value

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, index, postgresql-performance, pattern-matching

I have a table, where one column contains a substring of an url. It's always the leftmost part of the url without scheme.

| id | domain | column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | example.com | value1 | value2 |
| 2 | example.org | value3 | value4 |
| 3 | example.net/en-US | value5 | value6 |
| 4 | example.net/en-GB | value7 | value8 |

There's never an overlap in the domains, so there won't be a row with domain `example.net`, nor a domain that's empty.

I want to search and find the matching row given an url, for example `example.org/sub/sub/sub/test.html` it should return the row with id 2.

So far I've used `SELECT id FROM table WHERE 'example.org/sub/sub/sub/test.html' LIKE (domain ||  '%')` which gives what I want, but it always does a seq scan of the table, even though I have an index on the `domain` column. I was hoping that Postgres could make some conclusions and use the index anyway.

How can I improve the performance of this?

Comment: Have you thought about extracting the url portion from your input  first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: `SELECT id FROM table WHERE 'example.org/sub/sub/sub/test.html' LIKE (domain ||  '%')` *which gives what I want, but it always does a seq
> scan of the table, even though that I have an index on the domain
> column*

The kind of prefix-matching LIKE queries that can use a btree index have this form:

```
SELECT ... FROM table WHERE column LIKE parameter||'%'
```

where `parameter` is a constant and does not itself contain wildcard characters (`_` and `%`)

In the case of this question, that's the opposite: `parameter LIKE column||'%'`. For one thing, Postgres cannot know in advance if `column` may contain `_` or `%` characters for some rows. So it needs to read all of them. Even if there was a way to use the btree index to accelerate the matching, it could not be used here.

There's a [prefix](https://github.com/dimitri/prefix) extension that provides a datatype specifically optimized to find [longest prefix matches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_prefix_match) with the help of a GIST index. It seems like this would work fine for accelerating the kind of search you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like all possible substrings of your input are delimited with the character `/`. To illustrate my point:

```
SELECT string_agg(part, '/') OVER (ORDER BY ord) AS prefix
FROM   string_to_table('example.org/sub/test.html', '/') WITH ORDINALITY s(part, ord)
ORDER  BY ord DESC;

          prefix         
---------------------------
 example.org/sub/test.html
 example.org/sub
 example.org
```

Building on that assumption, here is a **highly efficient solution** to overcome the principal obstacle [Daniel](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/7119/daniel-v%C3%A9rit%C3%A9) explained:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_longest_prefix(_url text)
  RETURNS SETOF domain
  LANGUAGE plpgsql ROWS 1 STABLE AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _prefix text;
BEGIN
   FOR _prefix IN
      SELECT string_agg(part, '/') OVER (ORDER BY ord)
      FROM   string_to_table(_url, '/') WITH ORDINALITY s(part, ord)
      ORDER  BY ord DESC
   LOOP
      RETURN QUERY
      SELECT d.*
      FROM   domain d
      WHERE  d.domain = _prefix;
      
      EXIT WHEN FOUND;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM my_longest_prefix('example.org/sub/sub/sub/test.html');
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/n4NLjghP)

The function exits after the first hit. You get no row if nothing is found.

The "magic" is to switch operands in the filter expression so that the input can be the *pattern* and the query is ["sargable"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) again.
Also, after splitting the input to its atomic parts, we can match with `=` instead of `LIKE`. Now, left & right of the operator don't matter any more because `=` has a [`COMMUTATOR`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xoper-optimization.html#id-1.8.3.16.4) (itself) - as opposed to `LIKE` which does not. Related:

- [Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29245753/939860)

**If** the input can really be truncated at any position, replace the start of the loop with:

```
   FOR _prefix IN
      SELECT string_agg(part, '') OVER (ORDER BY ord)
      FROM   string_to_table(_url, null) ...
```

Only slightly less efficient. Results in one index seek per character in the input. But you'll probably take at least the leading domain as pattern ...

All you need is a **plain B-tree index** on `(domain)`. From what you told us, there may already be a `UNIQUE` constraint or index on the column providing said index.

[`string_to_table()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/curent/functions-string.html) requires Postgres 14 or later. Earlier versions offer various alternatives. The solution does not hinge on this implementation detail.

Comment: Thanks! I played around with this and wrote an alternative using unnest and string_to_array since we're on Postgres 13.  We finally went with the prefix extension though, as that was already supported in AWS RDS.

Comment: @Zyberzero Did you get a chance to compare performance of both solutions? A major bonus of this one: it only needs a btree index on `(domain)` that probably exists anyway.